# Finding row with the highest range in 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, range, row

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[][] data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 5}};
    int row = 0;
    int maxRow = data[row][0];
    int minRow = data[row][0];
    int rowCounter = 0;
    int rowRange = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) 
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) 
        {
            if (data[row][col] > maxRow) 
            {
                maxRow = data[row][col];
            }
            else if (data[row][col] < minRow) 
            {
                minRow = data[row][col];
            }
        }
        rowCounter++;
        rowRange = maxRow - minRow;
    }
    System.out.printf("The row with the greatest range is row #%d the range is %d%n", rowCounter, rowRange);
}
```

I'm looking to find the row with the greatest range and what row number its in, but I'm having some trouble.

The answer should be a "range of 7 row number 1"

With the code above I'm only getting the overall max range and row of everything. Any ideas?

Note: This is a small scale example I want to carry over to a huge array file.

Answer (score 0):

By doing:

```
rowRange = maxRow - minRow;
```

you're overriding the range again and again.

Do instead:

```
int tmpRowRange = maxRow - minRow;
if (tmpRowRange > rowRange)
    rowRange = tmpRowRange;
```

This way, you'll override `rowRange` only with values that are greater than the previous ones, which will leave you at the end of the iteration with the maximum range.